# append a list of vectors into a list of vectors

Tags: r

Let `x` be a list of vectors:

```
 a <-list( c(1,2,3),   c(4,5,6), c(7,8) ,c(9) )
 b <-list(c(11,22,33),c(44,55,66), c(77,88) ,c(99) )
 x <- list(a=a,b=b)
```

My desired output is the following:

```
>foo(x)

 list(c(1,2,3,11,22,33),c(4,5,6,44,55,66),c(7,8,77,88),c(9,99)
```

---

**Summary of Answers** by the Akrun and gfgm

1. `Map(c, a, b)`
2. `do.call(Map, c(f = "c", unname(x)))`
3. `mapply(function(i, j){c(i,j)}, a, b)`

Comment: you can try `Map(c, a, b)`  (change based on the change in example)

Comment: Thank you @akrun!! yes !! I have to learn about `lapply()` and I also think the `lapply()' is used but not sure  !!  Sorry, Cafe will be close !! I can only reply after 24 hour.

Comment: also, if you have already created the `list` 'x', then `do.call(Map, c(f = c, unname(x)))`

Comment: More precisely,  `do.call(Map, c(f = "c", unname(x)))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a good use case for `mapply()`

```r
a <-list( c(1,2,3),   c(4,5,6), c(7,8) ,c(9) )
b <-list(c(11,22,33),c(44,55,66), c(77,88) ,c(99) )

mapply(function(i, j){c(i,j)}, a, b)
#> [[1]]
#> [1]  1  2  3 11 22 33
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1]  4  5  6 44 55 66
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1]  7  8 77 88
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> [1]  9 99
```